# Gap above my main container div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've put together a very simple web app. I can't figure out how to get rid of the top gap in the smallest media query, despite having tried various methods & read a few other questions and tutorials online.

[Here](http://kennethfrancis.com/roadtrip/) is a link to the app. Any other tips are greatly appreciated. The stylesheet is a bit haphazard and I will go through and clean it up, but I'm still early enough on the learning curve that I will eat up any & all help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will get better answers if you post the relevant code in your question (ie: the "smallest media" you are talking about).

Comment: @Frederik.L, what's best practice when I don't know which part of the code is causing the issue? Post snippets of everything I *think* it might be? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what gap are you talking about but it seems like you haven't resetted the default browser `margin` so use this in your stylesheet - line 29

```
h1 {
   margin: 0;
}
```

And you are already using `*` selector, so instead of using `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` on `body`, use it on `*` instead..

Answer (score 2):

remove the top margin of your h1

```
h1 { margin-top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#calcPanel h1 {
padding: 8%;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `margin-top` from your div.

```
#calcPanel {
   width: 38%;
   height: 95vh;
   margin-left: 8%;
   margin-top: 1vh;    /* replace this with     margin-top: 0px; */
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: This style is only in effect when the screen is wider than 1100px. I'm wondering what's going on in this section the 320-768 section. Can't see what would be affecting it. The margin is greater than 1vh when the window is small anyway